# What location format does OpenStreetMap use in the embedded html?

Tags: html, embed, openstreetmap

I'm trying to use Lat/Long variables to update an embedded OpenStreetMap map.

However the link in the iframe has 4 numbers in it instead of 2, (eg: `-10.5029`, `36.3151`, `38.5400`, `54.2652`).

Could someone tell me what format this is called as I'd like to convert my Lat/Long numbers into it?

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-15.996
%2C36.31512514748051%2C33.04687500000001%2C54.265224078605684&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe><br/>
<small><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/46.012/8.525">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates in the URL of your `src` attribute also have 2 numbers before the decimal point, but the comma has been replaced with '%2C'. You can just replace it back with a comma and use your own coordinates. It will give you the same result.

**EXAMPLE**

Before     `-15.996%2C36.31512514748051%2C33.04687500000001%2C54.265224078605684`

After     `-15.996,36.31512514748051,33.04687500000001,54.265224078605684`

**CODE**

```html
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-15.996
,36.31512514748051,33.04687500000001,54.265224078605684&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe><br/>
<small><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/46.012/8.525">View Larger Map</a></small>
```